# format list of dynamic sidebar

Tags: css, wordpress, sidebar

I've registered a dynamic sidebar using the following code:

```
if(function_exists('register_sidebar')){
    register_sidebar(array('name' => 'appleQuery'));
}
```

I use this to display a list of categories, however I am struggling in knowing how to style this list??

I can't figure it out does anyone have any hints on where I should add the css for this?

Answer (score 0):

Check the source to see what classes or IDs are associated with the new sidebar. Modify those classes or IDs in your CSS.

Comment: the sidebar is held in this <div id="rightbar" style="float:left;width:25%;padding-left:5%"> but each link is built by a wordpress plugin, if I had the <ul> etc of the above div set - would that override the interior <li>s put in place by the plugin? I really do struggle with CSS